# Can you increment a long literal using the ++ operator and have access to the whole long literal range in java?

Tags: java, long-integer

I am writing a makeshift little private 'block chain' for illustrative purposes to be used as a teaching tool. I have all the core functionality ironed out, but I was thinking about some of the more peculiar aspects of block chain and found myself wondering about longs in java. The 'miner' method I have built into the application increments a nonce value of type long with the ++ operator until a condition is met. My question is, if I wanted to avoid (or at least greatly prolong) the chance of exhausting the integer nonce space (2147483647), if I initialized the starting nonce value I pass to the miner method with Nonce = 0L; could I increment it with the ++ operator and make use of the full long literal range?

It's my understanding that Bitcoin uses a special input value into the transaction, and/or some miners will slightly change the time stamp for "ExtraNonce" but since this is just for illustrative purposes I don't want to go as far as including something similar into the app.

I can provide code snippets if anyone wants to see them for any reason, any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

**Code below:**

(please don't heckle me on my questionable if/else control logic, this isn't a legitimate production application and I am still a novice in java)

This is the code from the launcher class that calls the miner method:

```
 } else if (cliInput.contentEquals("mine")) {
                Scanner howMany = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("\n");
                System.out.println("Enter number of blocks to mine: \n");
                int howManyBlocks = howMany.nextInt();
                int numBlocksMined = 0;
                while (howManyBlocks >= numBlocksMined) {
                    MainChain mc = new MainChain();
                    long indexValue = (HashArray.hashArray.size() / 8);
                    long timeStamp = mc.getUnixTimestamp();
                    String data = helpers.SHA256.generateHash(pubKey + addressKey);
                    String previousHash = mc.getPreviousBlockHash();
                    ChainBuilder cb = new ChainBuilder();
                    cb.miner(indexValue, timeStamp, data, 0, previousHash, 5);
                    numBlocksMined++;
                }
```

Here is the core of the miner method:

```
public void miner(long index, long currentTimeMillis, String data, long Nonce, String previousBlockHash, int difficulty) throws InterruptedException {
        this.index = index;
        this.currentTimeMillis = currentTimeMillis;
        this.pszTimeStamp = pszTimeStamp;
        this.Nonce = Nonce;
        this.previousBlockHash = previousBlockHash;
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
        this.data = data;
        boolean iterator = true;

        String blockHeader = (index + currentTimeMillis + data + Nonce + previousBlockHash + difficulty);
        String hash = SHA256.generateHash(blockHeader);

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("\n");
                System.out.println("Current hash rate: " + hashRate + " " + "hash/s");
            }
        }, 0, 3000);

        while (iterator) {
            blockHeader = (index + currentTimeMillis + data + Nonce + previousBlockHash + difficulty);
            hash = SHA256.generateHash(blockHeader);
            if (difficulty == 1) {

                if (!hash.startsWith("0")) {
                    Nonce++;
                    endTime = System.nanoTime();
                    deltaN = endTime - startTime;
                    deltaS = (deltaN / 1000000000);
                    hashRate = (Nonce / deltaS);

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Hash found!");
                    System.out.println("[" + hash + "]");
...............
```

What I am wondering is if I pass 0L instead of 0 to the miner method, will I have access to the whole range?

So instead of:

```
cb.miner(indexValue, timeStamp, data, 0, previousHash, 5);
```

Could I pass it like this to make use of the whole long literal range?

```
cb.miner(indexValue, timeStamp, data, 0L, previousHash, 5);
```

Comment: could you share some code?

Comment: If the miner method takes an integer, passing a `0L` doesn't make sense. Please expand on what you mean.

Comment: I added code snippets. The Nonce is of type long, but it's my understanding that unless you explicitly tell the compiler it's a long literal with the "L" suffix, it only has the same range as an integer.

Comment: So much text and so much code for such a trivial question. The answer is what happened when you tried it. Don't make mountains out of molehills.

Comment: I'm new to java, and to be fair I didn't post code with it initially, someone requested it, I just wanted to make sure there was context to what I was saying since someone immediately asked for code.. so I don't really think this deserves to be down voted, especially since the question did show some research effort. But alas, it did work, and I did receive an answer, which I accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for long ++ the instruction set `ladd` will be used (`iadd` for int).

See [6.5 Instruction#s#ladd](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.ladd)

---

Since your question totally changed with your edit and I still saw it..

```
cb.miner(indexValue, timeStamp, data, 0, previousHash, 5);
```

If you pass the `0` like that it will be treated as an `int` so you can put only `MAX_INTEGER` there although the method parameter accepts a `long` (it will be treated as such in the method body).

Comment: Yay you beat me to an answer by a minute.

Comment: Haha my question didn't totally change, I just didn't know if the nonce was passed with the "L" suffix (thus making it a long literal) if you could still increment it using the ++ operator. Hence the title, Can you increment a long literal using the ++ operator. Thank you for your super prompt responses every one! I updated the title for clarity. (:

Answer (score 3):

The `++` operator works as expected on `long` variables.